# What is the difference between `print(x)` and `print(*x)` in python 3?

Tags: python, printing

I can't remember where I saw this but I don't understand what's going on here. What use does `print(*x)` provide?
The following code:

```
x = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
print(x)
print(*x)

y = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(y)
print(*y)

z = 1, 2, 3, 4
print(z)
print(*z)
```

Gives the following output:

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4)]
(1, 2) (3, 4)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
1 2 3 4
(1, 2, 3, 4)
1 2 3 4
```

I see what is happening but I don't know what is happening. In the previous cases, it just outputs them without any brackets or commas.
But when I use this with a dictionary:

```
a = {1: "a", 2: [1, 2, 3], 3: (4, 5, 6)}
print(a)
print(*a)
```

I only get the keys back with the second print:

```
{1: 'a', 2: [1, 2, 3], 3: (4, 5, 6)}
1 2 3
```

Comment: regarding dictionaries, iterating over a dictionary iterates over the *keys*. When you unpack an argument using `*`, it simply iterates over your container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been described [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) that `*` will "unpack the arguments out of a list or tuple". When you `print(*var)`, it just like printing multiple variables:

```
x = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
print(*x)
# (1, 2) (3, 4)
# Same as follow
for v in x:
    print(v, end=' ')
```

When you unpack a `dict`, it returns the key of the `dict`. That's why you only get the keys back by `print(*dict)`. Applying the same `for` loop and you got the same as `print(*a)`:

```
a = {1: "a", 2: [1, 2, 3], 3: (4, 5, 6)}
for v in a:
    print(v, end=' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

In python data types like list, dictionary.. 
 * will unpack values from it...

For Better understanding  ,
    a = ["someone",23]
    "hi my name {} my age is {} ".format(a[0],a[1])

You can achieve the same by , 
     "hi my name {} my age is {} ".format(*a)

Answer (score 0):

*x is a shorthand for value unpacking.

```
therefore for a list x (1, 2, 3, 4) 
*x is 1, 2, 3, 4 as unpacked values
```

Read [this](https://hangar.runway7.net/python/packing-unpacking-arguments) for more information on unpacking